# CSS image auto resize with bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have navbar from bootstrap on my website. Under this i want background-image with 100% width and 100% height. And under this bg-image will be next and then next....and on every bg-image will be some text. I tried evertyhing and nothing.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Thanks

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>title</title>
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="bootstrap/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="first_section">
            <div class="menu">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                    <div class="container">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">title</a>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">HOME</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">ABOUT ME</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">WORK</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <!-- end of class menu-->
            <div class="first_background"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="first_title">
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="second_section">
            <div class="second_background"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="third_section"></div>
        <div class="fourth_section"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body
 {
margin: 0px auto;
 }
  .first_background
 {
    background-image: url(../images/first_bg.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

Comment: what do you want, what's not working...?

Comment: image doesn't show up

Comment: Your "first_background" div has no content. It's probably 0x0 pixels. That's why you don't see it.....

Comment: to div "first_background" i have bg-image with size 100% and 100%....of course if i set parametrs to px image shows up, but i need it in %....for responsive

Comment: 100% is relative to the size of the div not the background image. 100% of 0 is still 0.